# How to fix the space in firefox and chrome?

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, space

The website that I made is good if I open with chrome, but, when I open it with firefox there is a space between the menu and the content. [This is the website](http://infigoasia.com). Do you know how to fix it? This website is developed on WordPress. So I don't know how to fix it.
Thanks..

Comment: it would be helpful if you paste your html here . Seems like you may have missed a tag somewhere

Comment: I'm new in wordpress website, and I dont know where the html file is

Comment: u can target only mozilla browser..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its looks good in mozilla and chrome

```
<div style="overflow:hidden" class="container">
```

or you can target only mozilla using

```
 <style type="text/css">
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {

.container{overflow:hidden  }

    }
    </style>
```

Comment: can I use the second one into my main css? because the website using Wordpress and I don't know how to called that css in the website if I make a new css file.

Comment: @hendraspt, just add overflow:hidden in existing container class in main css file. or u can add second method in ur main css file and clear cache and test it.

Comment: it quite work, but the content below the slider is cut a bit in the top. I tried to changing the another code into `@-moz-document url-prefix() {#primary-mono #main {  margin-top: -80px;}` but it's not working in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that Firefox is pushing the content down to make space for the images in the slider. Once the script kicks in and restyles the slider, Firefox is not automatically moving the content back up the page into its intended place.

Try setting:

```
   #sliderdiv {overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: what is hero-frame? and where should I put it?

Comment: here hero-frame refer to the div of slider .

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix it with firebug this code made it look good in Firefox:

```
#site-navigation { margin-bottom: 0px; }
#slider-wrapper { margin-top: 0px; }
```

Comment: it looks good only in a home page in firefox, but no in a chrome and another page/menu in firefox and chrome

Answer (score 0):

Put 
`overflow: hidden;` in `<div class="container">` and it will do the trick. This wont brake when watching it in Chrome.

Comment: hmm it works in both, chrome and firefox, but only in  a home page, in another page/menu like "advisory" there is a space in firefox and chrome

Answer (score 0):

First of all add this property in your container class

```
.container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And than reduce margin-bottom

```
#top-nav #site-navigation {
    margin-bottom: 42px;
}
```

> Works perfectly as expected.

Comment: I appreciate it but It just same like put "overflow: hidden;" in .container and not looks good in chrome.